# How to assign the value to the image and after assignment, other's can't assign on the same image

Tags: php, html, mysqli

Since I'm really a beginner in system development, I don't have any clue on how to do this although I have already search for it.

I developed a system where the Emergency Room will be able to see whether there is an empty bed in the ward before admitting a patient.
Now, I can only put the image of the bed, but I don't know how to assign the bed to a patient and when assigned, the bed will be unable to the other patient.

[image]

and here the source code that I have

```
      <!-- Counts Section -->
      <section class="dashboard-counts section-padding">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xl-2 col-md-4 col-6">
              <div class="wrapper count-title d-flex">
                <div class="icon"><i class="icon-user"></i></div>
                <div class="img"><img src="malebed.png" width="100" height="100"  alt=""/>
                  <div class="name">1</div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xl-2 col-md-4 col-6">
              <div class="wrapper count-title d-flex">
                <div class="icon"><i class="icon-user"></i></div>
                <div class="img"><img src="malebed.png" width="100" height="100"  alt=""/>
                  <div class="name">2</div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div> 

            <div class="col-xl-2 col-md-4 col-6">
              <div class="wrapper count-title d-flex">
                <div class="icon"><i class="icon-user"></i></div>
                <div class="img"><img src="malebed.png" width="100" height="100"  alt=""/>
                  <div class="name">3</div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

           <div class="col-xl-2 col-md-4 col-6">
              <div class="wrapper count-title d-flex">
                <div class="icon"><i class="icon-user"></i></div>
                <div class="img"><img src="malebed.png" width="100" height="100"  alt=""/>
                  <div class="name">4</div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-xl-2 col-md-4 col-6">
              <div class="wrapper count-title d-flex">
                <div class="icon"><i class="icon-user"></i></div>
                <div class="img"><img src="malebed.png" width="100" height="100"  alt=""/>
                  <div class="name">5</div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-xl-2 col-md-4 col-6">
              <div class="wrapper count-title d-flex">
                <div class="icon"><i class="icon-user"></i></div>
                <div class="img"><img src="malebed.png" width="100" height="100"  alt=""/>
                  <div class="name">6</div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>


            <div class="col-xl-2 col-md-4 col-6">
              <div class="wrapper count-title d-flex">
                <div class="icon"><i class="icon-user"></i></div>
                <div class="img"><img src="malebed.png" width="100" height="100"  alt=""/>
                  <div class="name">7</div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>


            <div class="col-xl-2 col-md-4 col-6">
              <div class="wrapper count-title d-flex">
                <div class="icon"><i class="icon-user"></i></div>
                <div class="img"><img src="malebed.png" width="100" height="100"  alt=""/>
                  <div class="name">8</div>
                </div>
              </div>
           </div>
           <p>

           <div class="col-xl-2 col-md-4 col-6">
              <div class="wrapper count-title d-flex">
                <div class="icon"><i class="icon-user"></i></div>
                <div class="img"><img src="malebed.png" width="100" height="100"  alt=""/>
                  <div class="name">9</div>
                </div>
              </div>
           </div>
           <p>

           <div class="col-xl-2 col-md-4 col-6">
              <div class="wrapper count-title d-flex">
                <div class="icon"><i class="icon-user"></i></div>
                <div class="img"><img src="malebed.png" width="100" height="100"  alt=""/>
                  <div class="name">10</div>
                </div>
              </div>
           </div>
           <p>
           <div class="col-xl-2 col-md-4 col-6">
              <div class="wrapper count-title d-flex">
                <div class="icon"><i class="icon-user"></i></div>
                <div class="img"><img src="malebed.png" width="100" height="100"  alt=""/>
                  <div class="name">11</div>
                </div>
              </div>
           </div>
           <p>
           <div class="col-xl-2 col-md-4 col-6">
              <div class="wrapper count-title d-flex">
                <div class="icon"><i class="icon-user"></i></div>
                <div class="img"><img src="malebed.png" width="100" height="100"  alt=""/>
                  <div class="name">12</div>
                </div>
              </div>
           </div>
           <p>
           <div class="col-xl-2 col-md-4 col-6">
              <div class="wrapper count-title d-flex">
                <div class="icon"><i class="icon-user"></i></div>
                <div class="img"><img src="malebed.png" width="100" height="100"  alt=""/>
                  <div class="name">13</div>
                </div>
              </div>
           </div>

           <div class="col-xl-2 col-md-4 col-6">
              <div class="wrapper count-title d-flex">
                <div class="icon"><i class="icon-user"></i></div>
                <div class="img"><img src="malebed.png" width="100" height="100"  alt=""/>
                  <div class="name">14</div>
                </div>
              </div>
           </div>

           <div class="col-xl-2 col-md-4 col-6">
              <div class="wrapper count-title d-flex">
                <div class="icon"><i class="icon-user"></i></div>
                <div class="img"><img src="malebed.png" width="100" height="100"  alt=""/>
                  <div class="name">15</div>
                </div>
              </div>
           </div>

           <div class="col-xl-2 col-md-4 col-6">
              <div class="wrapper count-title d-flex">
                <div class="icon"><i class="icon-user"></i></div>
                <div class="img"><img src="malebed.png" width="100" height="100"  alt=""/>
                  <div class="name">16</div>
                </div>
              </div>
           </div>

           <div class="col-xl-2 col-md-4 col-6">
              <div class="wrapper count-title d-flex">
                <div class="icon"><i class="icon-user"></i></div>
                <div class="img"><img src="malebed.png" width="100" height="100"  alt=""/>
                  <div class="name">17</div>
                </div>
              </div>
           </div>

           <div class="col-xl-2 col-md-4 col-6">
              <div class="wrapper count-title d-flex">
                <div class="icon"><i class="icon-user"></i></div>
                <div class="img"><img src="malebed.png" width="100" height="100"  alt=""/>
                  <div class="name">18</div>
                </div>
              </div>
           </div>

           <div class="col-xl-2 col-md-4 col-6">
              <div class="wrapper count-title d-flex">
                <div class="icon"><i class="icon-user"></i></div>
                <div class="img"><img src="malebed.png" width="100" height="100"  alt=""/>
                  <div class="name">19</div>
                </div>
              </div>
           </div>

           <div class="col-xl-2 col-md-4 col-6">
              <div class="wrapper count-title d-flex">
                <div class="icon"><i class="icon-user"></i></div>
                <div class="img"><img src="malebed.png" width="100" height="100"  alt=""/>
                  <div class="name">20</div>
                </div>
              </div>
           </div>

           <div class="col-xl-2 col-md-4 col-6">
              <div class="wrapper count-title d-flex">
                <div class="icon"><i class="icon-user"></i></div>
                <div class="img"><img src="malebed.png" width="100" height="100"  alt=""/>
                  <div class="name">21</div>
                </div>
              </div>
           </div>

           <div class="col-xl-2 col-md-4 col-6">
              <div class="wrapper count-title d-flex">
                <div class="icon"><i class="icon-user"></i></div>
                <div class="img"><img src="malebed.png" width="100" height="100"  alt=""/>
                  <div class="name">22</div>
                </div>
              </div>
           </div>

           <div class="col-xl-2 col-md-4 col-6">
              <div class="wrapper count-title d-flex">
                <div class="icon"><i class="icon-user"></i></div>
                <div class="img"><img src="malebed.png" width="100" height="100"  alt=""/>
                  <div class="name">23</div>
                </div>
              </div>
           </div>

           <div class="col-xl-2 col-md-4 col-6">
              <div class="wrapper count-title d-flex">
                <div class="icon"><i class="icon-user"></i></div>
                <div class="img"><img src="malebed.png" width="100" height="100"  alt=""/>
                  <div class="name">24</div>
                </div>
              </div>
           </div>

           <div class="col-xl-2 col-md-4 col-6">
              <div class="wrapper count-title d-flex">
                <div class="icon"><i class="icon-user"></i></div>
                <div class="img"><img src="malebed.png" width="100" height="100"  alt=""/>
                  <div class="name">25</div>
                </div>
              </div>
           </div>

          <div class="col-xl-2 col-md-4 col-6">
              <div class="wrapper count-title d-flex">
                <div class="icon"><i class="icon-user"></i></div>
                <div class="img"><img src="malebed.png" width="100" height="100"  alt=""/>
                  <div class="name">24</div>
                </div>
              </div>
           </div>

           <div class="col-xl-2 col-md-4 col-6">
              <div class="wrapper count-title d-flex">
                <div class="icon"><i class="icon-user"></i></div>
                <div class="img"><img src="malebed.png" width="100" height="100"  alt=""/>
                  <div class="name">25</div>
                </div>
              </div>
           </div>

           <div class="col-xl-2 col-md-4 col-6">
              <div class="wrapper count-title d-flex">
                <div class="icon"><i class="icon-user"></i></div>
                <div class="img"><img src="malebed.png" width="100" height="100"  alt=""/>
                  <div class="name">26</div>
                </div>
              </div>
           </div>

           <div class="col-xl-2 col-md-4 col-6">
              <div class="wrapper count-title d-flex">
                <div class="icon"><i class="icon-user"></i></div>
                <div class="img"><img src="malebed.png" width="100" height="100"  alt=""/>
                  <div class="name">27</div>
                </div>
              </div>
           </div>

           <div class="col-xl-2 col-md-4 col-6">
              <div class="wrapper count-title d-flex">
                <div class="icon"><i class="icon-user"></i></div>
                <div class="img"><img src="malebed.png" width="100" height="100"  alt=""/>
                  <div class="name">28</div>
                </div>
              </div>
           </div>

           <div class="col-xl-2 col-md-4 col-6">
              <div class="wrapper count-title d-flex">
                <div class="icon"><i class="icon-user"></i></div>
                <div class="img"><img src="malebed.png" width="100" height="100"  alt=""/>
                  <div class="name">29</div>
                </div>
              </div>
           </div>

           <div class="col-xl-2 col-md-4 col-6">
              <div class="wrapper count-title d-flex">
                <div class="icon"><i class="icon-user"></i></div>
                <div class="img"><img src="malebed.png" width="100" height="100"  alt=""/>
                  <div class="name">30</div>
                </div>
              </div>
           </div>
```

Any advice will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Way too much code, you only need to post the parts which are relevant. Looks like it's all HTML, the status of the bed will be stored in the database, no? Show us your server side code with database queries

Comment: yes, it still in html since I don't know where to put the php sign since each beds are put there using hardcode.

Comment: Well, therein lies your problem. You need to remove the hardcode for the beds and instead perform a database query for the bed status. Then loop through the result and output dynamic HTML which reflects the status of each bed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your links, you can try to add an action in the link like this

```
echo '<li><a href="?action=selected&id={$someID}">Wad 1</a></li>';
```

after which you can use the get method to changed the status of the beds.

```
if(isset($_GET['id'] && $_GET['action'] == "selected"){
ward_table_selected() // function that changes the status of the table to selected
}
```

Note: make `$selected=false;` as your default and use the function to select it.

I hope this gave you an idea on how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you already have tables in your DB for beds and patients. Also, I assume that each record of bed in your DB has column `patient_id`(or something like that)

So, when you load this page, load beds from DB and insert them in your page via `foreach`. If bed is empty, then wrap this image in link to some kind of form where personnel can write data about patient or something like that. If bed is already taken by other patient just show bed's image without plus sign.

I am ready to extend my question with more precise suggestions, but I need to see your server side code, DB structure and may be process of patient registration

Comment: Thank you. I already have that, but I may have to try your suggestion first, I will update it soon when I have finished doing as you suggested.